# Installation of R packages using Rtools from source fails - how to fix collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: r, mingw, rtools

I need to install R packages from source.
This fails for ROracle, dplyr, purrr with a compilation error (see below). Interestingly it does not fail for ggplot2.

I am running R-Portable 3.6.1 64bits on Windows 7 with Rtools 3.5.0.4. 
Relevant local environment variables are

BINPREF = C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin

PATH = C:\Rtools\bin; %R_HOME%;C:\Rtools\mingw_$(WIN)\bin

I have no admin rights on this PC, this is why system path variables or registry entries mightnot have been set in the 'installation' process of Rtools, but I am not sure, if this is really the issue here.

FAIL:

```
> install.packages("ROracle", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 308252 bytes (301 KB)
downloaded 301 KB

'\\XXXXXXX$\XXXXX.HOME\Redirected_Profile\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** Paket 'ROracle' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
Oracle Client Shared Library 64-bit - 11.2.0.1.0 Operating in ORACLE_HOME environment.
found Oracle Client C:/PROGRA~1/ORACLE/CLIENT~1/bin
found Oracle Client include C:/PROGRA~1/ORACLE/CLIENT~1/oci/include
copying from C:/PROGRA~1/ORACLE/CLIENT~1/oci/include
** libs
Warnung: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PORTAB~1/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/include" -DNDEBUG -I./oci         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PORTAB~1/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/include" -DNDEBUG -I./oci         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o ROracle.dll tmp.def rodbi.o rooci.o C:/PROGRA~1/ORACLE/CLIENT~1/bin/oci.dll -LC:/PORTAB~1/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/bin/x64 -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
keine DLL erzeugt
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ROracle'
* removing 'C:/PortableProgramms/R-Portable_3_6_1/App/R-Portable/library/ROracle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOIAGJs\downloaded_packages’
```

NO FAIL:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3204655 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

'\\XXXXXXXXXX$\XXXXXX.HOME\Redirected_Profile\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** Paket 'ggplot2' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'ggplot2'
    finding HTML links ... fertig
    absoluteGrob                            html  
    add_theme                               html  
    aes                                     html  
    aes_                                    html  
    aes_all                                 html  
    aes_auto                                html  
    aes_colour_fill_alpha                   html  
    aes_group_order                         html  
    aes_linetype_size_shape                 html  
    aes_position                            html  
    annotate                                html  
    annotation_custom                       html  
    annotation_logticks                     html  
    annotation_map                          html  
    annotation_raster                       html  
    as.list.ggproto                         html  
    as_labeller                             html  
    autolayer                               html  
    autoplot                                html  
    benchplot                               html  
    borders                                 html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/borders.Rd:26: file link 'pathGrob' in package 'grid' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    calc_element                            html  
    combine_vars                            html  
    continuous_scale                        html  
    coord_cartesian                         html  
    coord_fixed                             html  
    coord_flip                              html  
    coord_map                               html  
    coord_munch                             html  
    coord_polar                             html  
    coord_trans                             html  
    cut_interval                            html  
    diamonds                                html  
    discrete_scale                          html  
    draw_key                                html  
    economics                               html  
    element                                 html  
    element_grob                            html  
    expand_limits                           html  
    expand_scale                            html  
    facet_grid                              html  
    facet_null                              html  
    facet_wrap                              html  
    faithfuld                               html  
    find_panel                              html  
    fortify-multcomp                        html  
    fortify                                 html  
    fortify.lm                              html  
    fortify.map                             html  
    fortify.sp                              html  
    geom_abline                             html  
    geom_bar                                html  
    geom_bin2d                              html  
    geom_blank                              html  
    geom_boxplot                            html  
    geom_contour                            html  
    geom_count                              html  
    geom_density                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/geom_density.Rd:66: file link 'bw.nrd' in package 'stats' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    geom_density_2d                         html  
    geom_dotplot                            html  
    geom_errorbarh                          html  
    geom_hex                                html  
    geom_histogram                          html  
    geom_jitter                             html  
    geom_linerange                          html  
    geom_map                                html  
    geom_path                               html  
    geom_point                              html  
    geom_polygon                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/geom_polygon.Rd:40: file link 'pathGrob' in package 'grid' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    geom_qq                                 html  
    geom_quantile                           html  
    geom_ribbon                             html  
    geom_rug                                html  
    geom_segment                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/geom_segment.Rd:89: file link 'curveGrob' in package 'grid' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    geom_smooth                             html  
    geom_spoke                              html  
    geom_text                               html  
    geom_tile                               html  
    geom_violin                             html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/geom_violin.Rd:77: file link 'bw.nrd' in package 'stats' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    gg-add                                  html  
    gg_dep                                  html  
    ggplot                                  html  
    ggplot2-ggproto                         html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

    ggplot2-package                         html  
    ggplotGrob                              html  
    ggplot_add                              html  
    ggplot_build                            html  
    ggplot_gtable                           html  
    ggproto                                 html  
    ggsave                                  html  
    ggsf                                    html  
    ggtheme                                 html  
    graphical-units                         html  
    guide-exts                              html  
    guide_colourbar                         html  
    guide_legend                            html  
    guides                                  html  
    hmisc                                   html  
    is.Coord                                html  
    is.facet                                html  
    is.ggplot                               html  
    is.rel                                  html  
    is.theme                                html  
    label_bquote                            html  
    labeller                                html  
    labellers                               html  
    labs                                    html  
    last_plot                               html  
    layer                                   html  
    layer_sf                                html  
    limits                                  html  
    lims                                    html  
    luv_colours                             html  
    map_data                                html  
    max_height                              html  
    mean_se                                 html  
    merge_element                           html  
    midwest                                 html  
    mpg                                     html  
    msleep                                  html  
    position_dodge                          html  
    position_identity                       html  
    position_jitter                         html  
    position_jitterdodge                    html  
    position_nudge                          html  
    position_stack                          html  
    presidential                            html  
    print.ggplot                            html  
    print.ggproto                           html  
    qplot                                   html  
    reexports                               html  
    remove_missing                          html  
    render_axes                             html  
    render_strips                           html  
    resolution                              html  
    scale_alpha                             html  
    scale_brewer                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/scale_brewer.Rd:37: file link 'brewer.pal' in package 'RColorBrewer' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    scale_colour_continuous                 html  
    scale_continuous                        html  
    scale_date                              html  
    scale_discrete                          html  
    scale_gradient                          html  
    scale_grey                              html  
    scale_hue                               html  
    scale_identity                          html  
    scale_linetype                          html  
    scale_manual                            html  
    scale_shape                             html  
    scale_size                              html  
    scale_type                              html  
    scale_viridis                           html  
    seals                                   html  
    sec_axis                                html  
    set_last_plot                           html  
    should_stop                             html  
    standardise_aes_names                   html  
    stat                                    html  
    stat_ecdf                               html  
    stat_ellipse                            html  
    stat_function                           html  
    stat_identity                           html  
    stat_sf_coordinates                     html  
    stat_summary                            html  
    stat_summary_2d                         html  
    stat_unique                             html  
    summarise_plot                          html  
    summary.ggplot                          html  
    theme                                   html  
    theme_get                               html  
    tidyeval                                html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:23: file link 'syms' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:25: file link 'expr' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:25: file link 'quo' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:28: file link 'exprs' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:29: file link 'quos' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:31: file link 'enexpr' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:31: file link 'enquo' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:35: file link 'enexprs' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGaJFrI/R.INSTALL3004479587e/ggplot2/man/tidyeval.Rd:35: file link 'enquos' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    transform_position                      html  
    translate_qplot_ggplot                  html  
    translate_qplot_lattice                 html  
    txhousing                               html  
    update_defaults                         html  
    update_labels                           html  
    vars                                    html  
    waiver                                  html  
    wrap_dims                               html  
    zeroGrob                                html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (ggplot2)
```

Comment: Just for information, I could not the solve the problem, but reinstalled Rtools (same Version!), then it worked